# Endeca "did you mean" navigation

Tags: java, endeca

How to provide **Did you mean suggestions** in endeca

Comment: Stop asking the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774715/endeca-did-you-mean-navigation

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you need the -dym flag enabled on your dgraph (this should be set in AppConfig.xml)

Then you need to extract the dym values in your application code, using the following code:
queryResult.getNavigation().getESearchReports().getDYMSUggestions();

This will return a list of ESearchDYMSUggestion objects each of which has a term which can be displayed to the user.

I am sure that you can find a good example of this on the Endeca Support portal.

Answer (score 1):

Nty parameter sets the Did You Mean feature for record search in the navigation query.

Java setter method ENEQuery.setNavERecSearchDidYouMean()

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51277_01/Mdex.650/pdf/DevGuide.pdf

For code example refer http://ourownjava.com/endeca/oracle-endeca-extract-tokens-navigation-query-result/